# If 3 polarizer experiment to teach quantum superposition can be explained classically, should it not be used to explain Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, education

Here is the link to the Dirac's three polarizer experiment.
https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/experiments/dirac_3-polarizers/

When a 90$^o$ and 0$^o$ polarizers are placed in front of each other, no light comes out of the other end.
When a 45$^o$ polarizing filter is placed between 90$^o$ and 0$^o$ filters, we surprisingly see light coming out from the setup.

A quantum explanation of polarization of light was given by Dirac.

However, I found a few sources where this is explained classically. The crux of their argument is that there are long molecules in the polarizer film. They not only attenuate the light but also rotate it. This combined effect can be used to explain the phenomenon classically.

http://alienryderflex.com/polarizer/
https://qr.ae/pGqOMb

Is this a good experiment to teach about Quantum Superposition. Is there is any flaw in the second argument?

Comment: You missed the point of the experiment. The demonstration is to show many things related to quantum mechanics without needing to actually use any kind of quantum mechanics. See it as an analogy. Light can be described by quantum mechanics, but all the polarization effects can also be dealt with classical electrodynamics, ie Maxwell eqs and no need for quantum mechanics. However that demonstration is a good way of showing what is meant by several concepts in QM. Just re-read the first two paragraphs of your link, and understand it!

Comment: If it can be explained classically then what is the point of invoking quantum mechanics. The experiment was proposed to show difference between classical and quantum mechanics. Then if it can be explained classically then what is the point of using it to teach quantum mechanics.

Comment: Light can be described by the time-dependent schrödinger equation, as light is also part of the QM world. If the fact that we have a model that has an almost identical set of differential equations (after re-arrangement) that pre-dates QM bugs you, then set up an experiment that shows clear QM effects that so far are only modeled via QM... I still think you are not getting the point of the experiment or what classical really means.

Comment: Ok you are saying this experiment is an analogy to explain QM.